# Adding a custom field in Paypal checkout

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

We are using Paypal checkout for our web app. We have the client lib where we are setting up the payment. In the back end, we are trying to capture the processed details via webhook. We tested this on a sandbox account. The webhook is sending all the details as expected except the custom field. We need the custom field in order to associate a payment with a certain service.

In our web app, we have the following:

```
  paypalConfig = {
    env: 'sandbox',
    style: {
          size: 'responsive',
          color: 'white',
          shape: 'rect',
          label: 'pay',
          layout: 'horizontal',
          tagline: 'false'
    },
    client: {
      sandbox: 'SANDBOX_ID',
    },
    commit: false,
    payment: (data, actions) => {
      console.log("data is", data, actions);
      return actions.order.create({
        payment: {
          transactions: [
            { amount: { total: this.finalAmount * 100, currency: 'USD' }, job_id: this.jobId }
          ]
        }
      });
    },
    onApprove: (data, actions) => {
          return actions.order.capture().then((details) => {
            // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
            // alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
            this.openModel('modal1');
      }).catch(err => {console.log("Error in authorize in paypal", err); this.openModel('modal2');})
    }
  }
```

As you can see, the payment handler is adding a job_id property for the transaction object. In the back end, we are listening for the following events:

Checkout order completed, Payment capture completed, Payment sale completed

We only need to listen for an event (like Payment Received) that tells us when the transaction goes through. I wasn't sure so I added all events that seemed relevant because there wasn't any event named Payment Received.

Can this be done as we are trying here? We don't get the custom job_id field in the webhook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you appear to be using old PayPal checkout.js , switch to the newest sdk.js

Second of all you are using a client-side only integration, switch to a proper client-server pattern. Here is the front-end: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

You will need two corresponding routes on your server, 'Set Up Transaction' and 'Capture Transaction', documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

With the above solution, you have an immediate, synchronous API response on payment capture. There is no need for an additional asynchronous notification from webhooks, so those will essentially become superfluous to you.

---

Once all the above is working and creating successful transactions for you, there's one more thing to consider: propagating failures. That is, what happens in the case of an unhappy path, if the buyer's funding source fails to capture, e.g. their card is declined? There is a guide for [how to send that error back to the UI](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/funding-failure/), so they can add or choose a different card.  Anyway, this is just the final detail to worry about.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We will definitely change the SDK. One point of interest though: if this is a synchronous call, that means the Paypal API response will be sent to the client in case of success or failure. This means that I can just add one more route in the back end where, after the API response is received, I can send the job_id and the transction ID for further tracking.

Comment: Your server routes to set up the transaction and capture the transaction can already be passing those details back and forth as needed. You won't need anything additional.

Comment: My apology first: "one more" was misleading. What I meant was if instead of 2 server endpoints, the payment is handled on client through the synchronous API request, we can wait on the client for the response and pass that along to the server on a single route. This can eliminate one route from the back end server and keep the payment handling logic on the client side.

Comment: I don't know what you are saying, but my recommendation remains that you have two routes as per https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: Let me try to explain: after making the payment from the web app, I get a response from PayPal API with status "completed". This means the payment was processed and amount charged was successfully transferred to the linked business account in PayPal. Before, I was trying to use web hook for this confirmation. Since the confirmation is available as a response on client side, now I can send one request to my back end with the transaction ID from response and job_id which, was also available on the client side. I don't need to rely on web hook to send that ID to my back end.

Comment: That being said, I don't need to expose two endpoints on my back end for these processed responses from PayPal API. I can expose one route in my API where, once the client app receives the PayPal completed response can send the ID and other details. Hope this helps to explain my rationale.

Comment: Why would you want to send the completed response from your client? That's 100% bad design and to be avoided, you are creating all kinds of bad issues for yourself.  Please do the sensible thing and create two routes to your server, one to set up the transaction and one to capture the transaction. Your server receives the completed response directly from PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a paypal form and then add custom as one of the values. Heres an example. Also, here is a great tutorial to walk you through it https://youtu.be/HIwRzATH6iU

```html
<form action="https://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="50.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="{MemberID}">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="youremail@business.example.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Whatever Item">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="600">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://www.yourwebsite.com/success/">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="https://www.yourwebsite.com/failure">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://www.yourwebsite.com/ipn">
    <input type="submit" value="Pay Now" name="submit" title="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```